# Drop Events on a Dell Powerswitch 2724

Tags: networking, switch, dell-powerconnect

I have a rather simple network setup here at an office. We utilize a Sonicwall TZ205N, plugged into a Business-Class Cable modem for internet, and plugged into three Dell PowerConnect 2724 gigabit switches.

The original configuration was a series of daisy-chaining and using an Off-The-Shelf Linksys router. Currently, I have each switch plugged directly into the router's built-in switch (Switch A,B,C plugged into port X0, X2, and X3 on the SonicWall). I don't have STP or anything fancy set up on the switches, just simple remote management via web. (They were originally all set to unmanaged!) In doing so, I've noticed drop events when I check the logs.

Two of the switches (B & C) have drop events on Port 1, which connects back to the router (One has nearly 10k over the course of 52 days!), while two switches (A & B) have drop events on workstation connected ports. I have to do more tracing, but I think they connect to our main file server and the FTP server we run in-house.

There aren't any major network issues (that I know of), and documentation on the cause/ramification of "Dropped Events" seems to be sparse at best. Are the switches just lacking the proper bandwidth, in which case I need to pitch some nicer Netgear GS748TS switches, or should I be doing some more hunting, tracing, and monitoring on the connected devices?

Comment: Do the switches connect to each other? If so, you had better enable STP on all of them. As for your drop events, check for duplex/speed mismatches on those ports and the hosts/devices connected to those ports.

Comment: I checked, they're all running 1000 Auto-Negotiation. The switches no longer connect to each other, instead they each plug into the Sonicwall Device.

Comment: If they're all set to Auto-negotiate have you verified that each port/host pair has negotiated the same duplex setting?

Comment: On the interfaces that connect to the router, yes. I will have to hunt down and check the other interfaces, but at least two interfaces that are having drop events are properly negotiating on both ends. (Port 1 on Switch B & C)